# Can one deduce independence if the conditional expectation is a constant?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be random variables with:
$E[X|Y]=c$ and $E[Y|X]=d$, where d,c are constants in $\mathbb{R}$.
Can we deduce that $X,Y$ are independent?

Comment: No. Consider the case when $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on a disc of finite radius centered on $(c,d)$.

Comment: You can deduce that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. (Provided they have finite second moments.) In fact, this uncorrelatedness follows already from   $E[X|Y]=c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These imply $E[X]=c$ and $E[Y]=d$. However, a constant conditional expectation does not imply independence.
Consider any independent random variable $(X,Z)$, and by defining $Y=ZX$ create $(X,Y)$ for which $E[ZX|X]=XE[Z|X]=XE[Z]=d$.
$X$ and $Y=ZX$ are not necessarily independent.

Comment: What abouf $E[X|ZX]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The last equality of E[ZX|X] is not correct. E[ZX|X] is equal to XE[Z] which is a non constant function of X.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).